# Angular Material Data Table is not getting filled with data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular Material and want to show a data table inside a custom modal and the data is not getting filled in, even not the header titles. Everything is empty.

Here is my History modal component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-history",
  templateUrl: "./history.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./history.component.scss"]
})
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ["position", "name", "weight", "symbol"];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: "Hydrogen", weight: 1.0079, symbol: "H"},
  {position: 2, name: "Helium", weight: 4.0026, symbol: "He"},
  {position: 3, name: "Lithium", weight: 6.941, symbol: "Li"},
  {position: 4, name: "Beryllium", weight: 9.0122, symbol: "Be"},
  {position: 5, name: "Boron", weight: 10.811, symbol: "B"},
  {position: 6, name: "Carbon", weight: 12.0107, symbol: "C"},
  {position: 7, name: "Nitrogen", weight: 14.0067, symbol: "N"},
  {position: 8, name: "Oxygen", weight: 15.9994, symbol: "O"},
  {position: 9, name: "Fluorine", weight: 18.9984, symbol: "F"},
  {position: 10, name: "Neon", weight: 20.1797, symbol: "Ne"},
  {position: 11, name: "Sodium", weight: 22.9897, symbol: "Na"},
  {position: 12, name: "Magnesium", weight: 24.305, symbol: "Mg"},
  {position: 13, name: "Aluminum", weight: 26.9815, symbol: "Al"},
  {position: 14, name: "Silicon", weight: 28.0855, symbol: "Si"},
  {position: 15, name: "Phosphorus", weight: 30.9738, symbol: "P"},
  {position: 16, name: "Sulfur", weight: 32.065, symbol: "S"},
  {position: 17, name: "Chlorine", weight: 35.453, symbol: "Cl"},
  {position: 18, name: "Argon", weight: 39.948, symbol: "Ar"},
  {position: 19, name: "Potassium", weight: 39.0983, symbol: "K"},
  {position: 20, name: "Calcium", weight: 40.078, symbol: "Ca"},
];
```

```css
:host {
  display: flex;
}

.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.mat-header-cell.mat-sort-header-sorted {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>History</h2>
<!-- <mat-dialog-content class="example-container"> -->
  <div class="example-container">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </mat-table>
  </div>
<!-- </mat-dialog-content> -->
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">OK</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Here is my Angular Material import module which I import into same module where I declare my `HistoryComponent`:

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import {
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatOptionModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatSortModule,
} from "@angular/material";

const materialModules = [
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatOptionModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatSortModule,
];

@NgModule ({
  imports: [...materialModules],
  exports: [...materialModules],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

The `HistoryComponent` is declared and also added to the entryComponents array.

When I open the modal in the browser, no data is displayed in the table:

```html
<mat-table _ngcontent-c19="" class="mat-table" matsort="" role="grid" ng-reflect-data-source="[object Object],[object Object">
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-header-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c19="" mat-row="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></tr></mat-table>
```

What is hapenning here? I am not getting any errors or whatsoever.

> StackBlitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assyye but suddenly it is working there and I have no clue why.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz example?

Comment: Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assyye but suddenly it works. Do not know why...

Comment: Please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbvana?file=src/app/app.module.ts I only added `BrowserAnimationsModule`

Comment: I have this in my original code and forgot it now. But why is it working now? I have done nothing different, except another module inbetween. Do you know why it is not working in my dev env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the version upgrade which happened on 3.5.2018. They changed the mat-table-api heavily without mentioning it in the documentation.

- Instead of `<mat-table>` it is `<table mat-table>` now.
- Instead of `<mat-header-cell>` it is `<th mat-header-cell>` now.
- Instead of `<mat-cell>` it is `<td mat-cell>` now.

Dear Angular Material team. Please add a shoutout to your documentation with breaking changes and such a big version upgrade from today to tomorrow. You get no notification anywhere and spending hours on it.